# HTML page print does not fit inside Letter paper when printed

Tags: html, css-position, css-print

I'm dealing with a large project and part of it is printing HTML pages.

However, we are dealing with the issue of pages do not fit within the Letter size paper.

Please see the following simple code: As you see the dimensions of the Letter paper are clearly specified. The page shows correctly on the web browser and even on the Print Preview page, it shows correctly. However, after printing on a US Letter size paper the word "Test" is cut off a bit on top and left. Also, the black border does not show on print. Why does this happen?

See below:

```css
<style>
/* Reset default margin and padding on body */

@page {
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Create a full-screen div */
.full-screen-div {
    width: 8.5in; /* 100% of the viewport width */
    height: 11in; /* 100% of the viewport height */
    Border: solid 5px
    }

.TR{
position:absolute;
margin-top:0;
margin-right:0;
font-size:24px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    
    <title>Full-Screen Div</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="full-screen-div">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
        <span class='TR'>Test</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the margins of the printer you're using. You'll probably find the printable area is not the full US Letter size

Comment: @ Daveboy my understanding is that when you in CSS set @Page{margin:0} that overrides printer margin settings.

Comment: @ Daveboy:  I tried setting printer margins to Default and none, still the  word Test is cuff off.

Comment: The margins on a printer are a physical limitation of the hardware. Overriding them in software isn't going to make a difference to what the printer can actually do. It's like asking a HD TV to display a 4K image that is centred on the screen but without shrinking the picture - you're going to lose the outside of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my research here for the future viewer.

I did a huge amount of research for 2 days looking all over the internet to find a solution.

The bottom line is when trying to print an HTML page, the print function in the browser is ***not*** a reliable way to preserve the layout.

I just saved the page as a PDF file on my computer and then the page was printed exactly as it should have.

Another option is to buy 3rd party HTML to PDF software that integrates with the coding language(I am using a C# app) and then dynamically create your pdf.

Comment: When you printed the PDF, did you have the scaling set to "Fit". Try changing to "100%" scale and you may lose the edges again

Answer (score 0):

That span is absolutely positioned, it has the default position `top: 0` and `left: 0`, but there is no parent/ancestor div that has `position: relative`, so `body` is by default regarded as the relative parent, NOT its direct parent `full-screen-div`.

I suggest to add `position: relative` to the `full-screen-div` to make that one act as the position anchor for the absoute position of `.TR` and that way have more control over its placement.

Comment: Added that I still got the same results. word Test was cutoff.  Can this be because of my cheap printer?

Comment: Could you please give it a try with your printer and let me know?